# My variables aren't passing to the function

Tags: javascript, php, function, var

UPDATE: Ali helped me get the values populating, but the issue now is that it's pulling the data from the last game option in the array every time. I need to click the game and show the info for that game. I've updated my code below.

ORIGINAL: I'm trying to fix a page that contains a form to search for nearby games and display the results. Once the results are displayed, I need to be able to click the results to show information for each of the games in a pop up window.

It is currently using the default values of the form to populate the popups, eg every club will show 6.15 as the time until I change the time of the search form, in which case they will all show that time as the time of the game within the pop up.

This is the code used to display the games:

```
<div class="game-search-result-outer pop-profile-view pop-profile-view1">
    <ul>
         <?php  $src_game = '';
           if(!empty($game_lists)){
            foreach($game_lists as $glist){  
               if($glist->count_golfer_join < $glist->golfer){  
                ?>
                <li class="game<?=$glist->id?>" onclick="getGameValue('<?=$glist->id?>','<?=$glist->club_name?>','<?=$src_game?>','<?=$glist->handicap_min?>','<?=$glist->handicap_max?>','<?= date("d/m/Y",strtotime($glist->start_date))?>');">
                    <a href="#" data-id="<?=$glist->id?>">
                        <div class="club-img">
                            <img src="<?=$src_game?>">
                        </div>
                        <h3><?=$glist->club_name?> <br> <?= date("d/m/Y",strtotime($glist->start_date))?> at <?= date("G:i a",strtotime($glist->start_time))?> <br> Handicap between <?=$glist->handicap_min?> and <?=$glist->handicap_max?></h3>
                    </a>
                    <input type="hidden" name="start_date<?=$glist->id?>" id="start_date<?=$glist->id?>" value="<?= date("d/m/Y",strtotime($glist->start_date))?>">
                </li>
         <?php }
           } }else{ echo "No Games Available, please refine your search" ;}                              ?>
         
        </ul>
</div>
```

Onclick, it activates this function:

```
<script>

function getGameValue(game_id,club_name,src,handicap_min,handicap_max) {
     var golf_handicap = '<?=$USERDETAILS->golf_handicap?>';    
     var start_date = $("#start_date"+game_id).val();
     //var start_date = '<?= date("d/m/Y",strtotime($glist->start_date))?>';
     var play_against = $("#play_against option:selected").text();
     var start_time = '<?= date("G:i a",strtotime($glist->start_time))?>';
     var handicap1 = $("#handicap1").val();
     var gofer = $("input[name='golfer']:checked").val();
     var handicapRange1 = handicap_min;                  
     var handicapRange2 = handicap_max; 
     var p = $('.game'+game_id+' > h3');
     
     if(golf_handicap<handicapRange1 || golf_handicap>handicapRange2){
         alert("Unfortunately you cannot join this game, your handicap "+golf_handicap+" is not within the handicap range.");
        
         document.location.reload();
         return false
     }  
      
    var data ='<div class="result-pop-box-img"><img src="'+src+'"></div><div class="result-pop-box-text"><h3>'+club_name+'</h3><p class="game<?=$glist->id?>">Hi <?=$USERDETAILS->first_name?>, you\’re about to join a game at '+club_name+' on '+ start_date +' at '+ start_time +' for '+ gofer +' golfers playing against '+ play_against +' with a handicap between '+ handicap1 +'. If this is correct, click the “Confirm” button. If you want to edit your booking, click cancel</p></div>'; 
     $("#getGameValueID").html(data);
     
}

</script>
```

Thank you for any help.

UPDATE

Here is the code for the form:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-control">
    <label>Location
       <?php  $zip = ($USERDETAILS->s_address)?', '.$USERDETAILS->zip:''.$USERDETAILS->zip;
       $location = $USERDETAILS->s_address.$zip;  ?>
        <span class="loc-icon"><input type="text" name="location" class="icon-input" id="location" value="<?=$location?>"></span> 
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control"> 
    <label>Date
        <span class="cal-icon">
        <div>
            <!--<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="start_date">-->
            <input type="date" id="start_date2" name="start_date2" value="<?php if($_GET['start_date2']){echo $_GET['start_date2'];}else { echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('+1 day', time()));} ?>" min="<?=date("Y-m-d",strtotime('+1 day', time()))?>"  max="<?=date("Y-m-d",strtotime('+1 year', time()))?>">
        </div>
        </span>
        <!--<input type="text" name="date" class="icon-input"></span>-->
    </label>
    </div>                                
    <div class="golfer-select">
        <div class="form-control">
            <label>Golfers</label>
            <?php if($_GET['golfer']==1) $gcheck = 'checked';
                  elseif($_GET['golfer']==2) $gcheck2 = 'checked';
                  elseif($_GET['golfer']==3) $gcheck3 = 'checked';

            ?>
            <div class="x3">
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="golfer" value="1" <?=$gcheck?>>
                <span>1</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="x3">
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="golfer" value="2" <?=$gcheck2?>>
                <span>2</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="x3">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="golfer" value="3" <?=$gcheck3?>>
                    <span>3</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>                          
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
    <label>Play Againts</label>
        <select name="play_against" id="play_against">
            
            <?php foreach($categories as $cate){ 
                    if($_GET['play_against']==$cate->id) { 
                    $csel = 'selected';
                 }else{ $csel = ''; }
                  ?>
        
                <option value="<?=$cate->id?>"<?=$csel?>><?=$cate->name?></option>
            <?php } ?>  
        </select>
    </div>                                
    
    <div class="form-control">
    
        
        <div class="time-range">
            <label>Start Time</label>
            <div class="range range-step range-step-popup">
                <input value="1" type="range" max="60" min="0" step="1" list="ticks2" onclick="getTimeValue();">
                <datalist id="ticks2">
                  <?php $minute=00; $counter=0;
                  for($start_time=06;$start_time<21;){
                      
                      if($minute>45){
                        $minute = 00;
                        $start_time++;
                      }?>
                      <option value="<?=$counter?>"><?=$start_time?>.<?=$minute?></option>
                     <?php 
                     $counter++;
                     $minute= $minute+15;
                      
                  }?>
                  
                  
                  
                </datalist>
                <output id="get_range" class="__range-output-square"></output>
            </div>
        
            <input type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time">
            <script>
            function getTimeValue() {
                var range_val = document.getElementById('get_range').innerHTML;
                document.getElementById('start_time').value=range_val;
            }
            </script>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-control">
    <div class="dis-range">
            <label>Distance (in miles)</label>
            <div class="range range-step range-step-popup">
                    <?php  $dist_val = array(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,50,60,75,100,125,150,200,300,500,1000,2000,3000,5000,10000);
                    
                     if(in_array($_GET['distance'],$dist_val)){
                         $key_val = array_search ($_GET['distance'], $dist_val);
                         $sel_dist_key = $key_val;
                     }else{
                         $sel_dist_key = 15;
                     } ?>
                    <input value="<?=$sel_dist_key?>" type="range" max="22" min="0" step="1" list="ticks3"  onclick="getValue();">
                    <datalist id="ticks3">
                      <option value="0">0</option>
                      <option value="1">5</option>
                      <option value="2">10</option>
                      <option value="3">15</option>
                      <option value="4">20</option>
                      <option value="5">25</option>
                      <option value="6">30</option>
                      <option value="7">35</option>
                      <option value="8">40</option>
                      <option value="9">50</option>
                      <option value="10">60</option>
                      <option value="11">75</option>
                      <option value="12">100</option>
                      <option value="13">125</option>
                      <option value="14">150</option>
                      <option value="15">200</option>
                      <option value="16">300</option>
                      <option value="17">500</option>
                      <option value="18">1000</option>
                      <option value="19">2000</option>
                      <option value="20">3000</option>
                      <option value="21">5000</option>
                      <option value="22">10000</option>
                    </datalist>
                    <output id="get_distance" class="__range-output-square"></output>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="distance" id="distance" value="">
            <script>
            function getValue() {
                var range_val = document.getElementById('get_distance').innerHTML;
                document.getElementById('distance').value=range_val;
            }
            </script>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-control">
    
        <div class="handi-range">
            <label>Handicap</label>
            
             <section class="range-slider range range-step range-step-popup">                                       

                <span class="rangeValues"></span>

                <input value="0" min="0" max="54" step="1" type="range">

                <input value="54" min="1" max="54" step="1" type="range">

               <datalist class="in-dots" id=""> 
                   <?php for ($handcap=0;$handcap<=54;$handcap++){ 
                     
                     echo '<option value="'.$handcap.'">'.$handcap.'</option>';
                  
                    } ?>
                </datalist>
                
                
                </section>
                <input type="hidden" name="handicap" id="handicap1">                                        
                

        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="sp20"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="green-btn-arrow" onclick="getInfo();">
    <!--<button class="green-btn-arrow">Search</button>-->
</form>
```

Comment: I did not understand your problem. you do not want the form to have the default value? And your function gets 5 inputs as you pass 6 in the code, just to know, it does not really an issue here.

Comment: Hi sorry, the form works fine, it's when the user clicks on one of the results that the issues arise. When the results of the search form are displayed, I want to click on them and have the correct information populate the <h3> tag. However, it is populating it with the default form values and I need help getting the right info to display. Hope that clarifies a bit and thanks!

Comment: The foreach in the first section of code works fine and displays the correct info. I want to show that info in the pop up that shows when a user clicks one of the results, however it shows default values from the form instead.

Comment: so if you want to change the h3 tag contents after the click. you probably should do it in the getGameValue function right? for doing that pass the extra input to that function like a counter in the form ($i) and create an attribute class for h3 like (class=$i). Then in the function get that element from the dom by its class and change the innerHtml. do you want me to write the code or it is fine?

Comment: if you could write the code that would be amazing my friend!

Comment: What does the HTML for your form look like (particularly the INPUT elements, such as start_date).  It would be helpful to see where the data is coming from.  And as a thought--you do only have each of these elements appear ONCE, right?

Comment: Hi, I've added the form to the code above, thanks for looking into it. These elements appear once on the page, and again as popups which I think might be causing the issue, but due to how it was built I can't figure out the best way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class attribute to each li;

```
<?php
   ...
   <!-- add class to li based on glist_id so you can access to each element in the getGameValue function-->
   <li class="game<?=$glist->id?>" onclick="getGameValue('<?=$glist->id?>','<?=$glist->club_name?>','<?=$src_game?>','<?=$glist->handicap_min?>','<?=$glist->handicap_max?>','<?= date("d/m/Y",strtotime($glist->start_date))?>', '<?= date("G:i a",strtotime($glist->start_time))?>');">
```

Now in your function

```
function getGameValue(game_id,club_name,src,handicap_min,handicap_max, start_date, start_time) {
    // remove these lines and add them to inputs
// var start_date = '<?= date("d/m/Y",strtotime($glist->start_date))?>';
// var start_time = '<?= date("G:i a",strtotime($glist->start_time))?>';
    
    // get h3 element
    var h3 = $('.game'+game_id+' > h3');
    
    // change the h3 innetHtml like here
}
```

other than this you can do whatever you want with that information inside the getGameValue function.

Comment: Thank you so much! So I've added the class to li, and the line to my function, but I'm not sure how to get to the next step where it now populates the correct info?

Comment: also, my bad, it's not the h3 tag, it's the <p> tag in var data

Comment: which element in the form (you updated) you want, to show the new information?

Comment: Hi, it's not the form I need to show new info sorry. When the form is completed it shows clickable images that fit the search criteria submitted in the form. These images also have information displayed underneath such as start time and handicap. All this information is correct. However, when I click the image a pop up appears which is supposed to display the same information but instead it shows the default values from the form. I hope that's a bit clearer for you and I do appreciate the help!

Comment: So, please tell me this line: var data ='<div class="result-pop-box-img"><img src="'+src+'"></div><div class="result-pop-box-text"><h3>'+club_name+'</h3><p>.....click cancel</p></div>'; is not working? because you said popup has issue and the class name is "result-pop-box-img".

Comment: That's where the problem is yes

Comment: Hi, thank you again for all this. The pop up isn't the issue, it's just where the problem is happening.

Comment: I think your problem is start_date and start_time. in your getGameValue function, you should not use any "$glist->" kinda thing. $glist populated with the last value in $game_lists. so every time the function is being called you should see the last value. you should pass this value to the function itself. I'm ganna update the answer you may check

Comment: Hi, I've think I've updated it correctly, but it's still passing the last value of glist. I'll update my code above. I think the values being passed to the function onclick are the values of the the last glist (as opposed to the current clicked one), but when I check inspect element each clickable game has the correct data held in the onclick.